# Creating an executable on Ubuntu 13

Tags: 13.04, scripts, executable

I read several answers saying that if I change the file properties to set the 'Allow execute as program' it will allow me to double click the file and it will launch.

Instead, when I try to do that for an .sh file it just opens it via gedit..

I also tried to chmod ugo+x the file but that didn't help.

Comment: I read at some other answer that if you run chmod ugo+x filename it will allow it to run when double clicking..

Comment: it's an .sh file @user68186

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the behaviour of Nautilus.

Open Nautilus - File - Preferences (Options) - Behaviour Tab.
Under "Executable text files" mark "Execute..." or just "Ask...", then you have the choice.

[image]

Comment: When I open Nautilus I don't see the File menu.. I have a 'settings' icon on the right hand side but that has properties and options for the folder I'm currently viewing...

Comment: It has to be in the main menue. In Nautilus there should be only one item in the main menu. It might be hidden if you use standard Ubuntu Desktop with Unity. So, activate a Nautilus window and bring the cursor to the upper border. The main menu should appear.